# how to multiply all rows by column of single matrix in pytorch in a vectorized way

Tags: python-3.x, math, deep-learning, pytorch

I need to multiply all rows of a matrix by column, i think with an example it will be clearer:

matrix is:

```
1,2,3 
4,5,6 
7,8,9
```

An i need an operation that returns:

```
28,80,162
```

But i can't find anything in the documentation and blogs and other SO question  only are related to matrix multiplication and dot product, which is not what i need in this case,how can it be achieved in a vectorized fashion(instead of for loop based) ?

For example this is easy to achieve for the case of sum like:

```
the_matrix.sum(dim=0)
```

But there's not something like:

```
the_matrix.mul(dim=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, there's no :

```
the_matrix.mul(dim=0)
```

But there's:

```
he_matrix.prod(dim=0)
```

Which does exactly what is needed.